# Hosting WCF on https with SSL

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, iis-7

I created an ASP.NET project and added a WCF service called RestService.svc. Here is the code in RestService.svc.cs.

```
 [ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true), AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class RestService : IRestService
    {
        public string SayHello()
        {
            return "Hello!!!";
        }
    }
```

Here is the service contract IRestService.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IRestService
{

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "SayHello")]
    string SayHello();
}
```

My configuration file is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

<customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="default.aspx">
            <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
        </customErrors>
  </system.web>


 <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="MyService.RestService" behaviorConfiguration="httpsBehavior">
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="webHttpBinding"
                  contract="MyService.IRestService"/>

        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpsBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="httpsBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>

    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>


 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

When I request .svc file in a browser, it returns the following messages:
RestService Service

**You have created a service.**

*To test this service, you will need to create a client and use it to call the service. You can do this using the svcutil.exe tool from the command line with the following syntax:*

The web application is hosted in IIS using SSL on port 15001. I also created an aspx page to see if I can access the site on https and it works. But when I call the service, it gives a black page in browser and 400: Bad Request message in Chrome Rest Client.

Comment: if you require REST service I suggest using web api that are more suited for this purpose. WCF works on a message base based protocol called SOAP that can be applied on HTTP calls.

Comment: What is the URL you use when WCF returns you the message? If your request ends with ".svc" then it is expected, as that won't be routed to the method you defined but a default page to explain the usage of WCF.

Comment: https ://example.com:15001/RestService.svc/SayHello is the URL I am using and it gives a blank page. (left a space intentionally here so it does not get formatted)